# error occuring while inserting data into database using php in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

If I assign values directly means it's inserting values into DB.

But if I use variables(like `$user`, `$pass`) to pass values in `members_model` class, it's showing error like below:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$user' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\models\members_model.php on line 5

**Model:**

members_model.php

```
    <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Members_model extends CI_Model 
    {
       $user = 'Vinayak';
       $pass = 'ggf';

        function get_members() 
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('users');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        function put_members()
        {

            $this->username = $_POST['user'];
            $this->password = $_POST['pass'];
            $this->db->insert('users', $this);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

NOTE: Please help me to resolve this error or tell me is there any better way to insert data into MySQL Database using codeIgniter in PHP

Answer (score 0):

When using a class, if you are defining variables, you need to use a access specifier with it.
Like in this case :

```
 class Members_model extends CI_Model 
    {
       $user = 'Vinayak';
       $pass = 'ggf';
```

should be :

```
 class Members_model extends CI_Model 
    {
      public/private/protected $user = 'Vinayak';
      public/private/protected  $pass = 'ggf';
```

and is you use this variable in same calss you can use them like `$this->user, $this->pass`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the access level as @Sankalp said, which is what's causing the error you shown, you have a problem in your insert method (you've been blocked by the missing acces specifier, but when you go on, you'll get that error too)

So,

```
class Members_model extends CI_Model 
{
  private $user = 'Vinayak';
  private $pass = 'ggf';
  // though, why creating class defaults for user and password?? what's the point?
```

Then, your function:

```
  function put_members()
  {     
    $this->username = $_POST['user'];
    $this->password = $_POST['pass'];
    $this->db->insert('users', $this);
  }
}
```

Is **wrong**: you're passing to the `insert()` method the *whole* object ( `$this` ) when you have to pass the **fields names** instead:

A better way to do that would be:

```
function put_members()
{

   $this->user = $this->input->post('user');
   $this->pass = $this->input->post('pass');
   $this->db->insert('users', array(
                                      'user' => $this->user, 
                                      'pass' => $this->pass
                                    )
                    );
}
```

Where 'user' and 'pass' are the column names of your 'users' table (change accordingly to your setup).

**Important note:** Let's not talk now about you storing the password in cleartext, which is *really* bad practice, but keep in mind that as soon as you have your model functioning you should focus on that issue too: use the best solution your php installation provides (`crypt()` with BLOWFISH would be pretty nice) or at the very very least `sha1()`